# Can't flush second time after the first row is deleted

Tags: symfony, doctrine

So I am basically trying to delete the existing row in my `verification_code` table and create new one. The deleting is fine but when the code reach `$this>codeRepository->flush();` error is thrown:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
> 'App\Entity\User#verificationCode' that was not configured to cascade
> persist operations for entity: App\Entity\VerificationCode@374. To
> solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
> this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
> the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
> cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
> 'App\Entity\VerificationCode#__toString()' to get a clue.

If I try to not flush when removing the old record, duplicate key error is thrown as expected.

```
#[Route(path: '/api/v1/resendVerificationCode', methods: 'POST')]
    public function resendVerificationCode(Request $request):JsonResponse
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->find($request->get('userId'));
        $this->codeRepository->remove($user->getVerificationCode(), true);

        $verificationCode = new VerificationCode();
        $this->codeRepository->add($verificationCode);
        $verificationCode->setUser($user);
        $this->codeRepository->flush();

        return new JsonResponse();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestions listed in the error?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. What is exactly the problem I am wondering. I am flushing on remove and just making new record. Plus my relations is OneToOne

Comment: This is a bit unusual: `$verificationCode->setUser($user);`  I would have expected `$user->setVerificationCode($codeVerification)`.  Are you sure the vc->setUser method calls user->setVC? I'm thinking that when you flush the second time the user is still pointing to the original vc.  Just a guess.

Comment: Yes ... i had to set the verificationCode to null in the user enitity `$user->setVerificationCode(null)` after removing it from db.

Comment: So does that mean it all works now?

Comment: I think you should flush after you've removed it. The EntityManager works as a UnitOfWork, so queries are managed by the EntityManager and may not be executed in the same order you have built it. 

But why not replace the current VerifcationCode data instead of the Entity? 
```$user->getVerificationCode()->refresh()```
Of-course, you have to build `refresh()` yourself in your `VerificationCode` entity.